# Plot a binary 3D matrix in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to represent a binary 3D matrix in a 3D plot (if possible not with mayavi.mlab). At every location (x,y,z) where the matrix has a 1 a point should be plotted. 
My matrix is built the following way:

```
import numpy as np
size = 21
my_matrix = np.zeros(shape = (size, size, size))
random_location_1 = (1,1,2)
random_location_2 = (3,5,8)
my_matrix[random_location_1] = 1
my_matrix[random_location_2] = 1
```

Now at the coordinates (1,1,2) and (3,5,8) a dot should be visible, everywhere else just empty space.
Is there any way to do this (e.g. with matplotlib?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need a scatter plot. Take a look at [this](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html) mplot3d tutorial. For me this worked:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

size = 21
m = np.zeros(shape = (size, size, size))
random_location_1 = (1,1,2)
random_location_2 = (3,5,8)
m[random_location_1] = 1
m[random_location_2] = 1

pos = np.where(m==1)
ax.scatter(pos[0], pos[1], pos[2], c='black')
plt.show()
```